# passing dataannotations from model to viewmodel

Tags: asp.net-mvc

in my mvc app i have a model and a related viewmodel.  When i bind to the model the displayfor / editorfor methods pick up the displayname data annotation and also the client validation works automatically.

When i bind the view to my viewmodel the data annotations are ignored. I realize i can put the validation / display name annotations on my viewmodel but would prefer not to have to duplicate or move them into the viewmodel. How do people handle this?

so far i have

```
[MetadataType(typeof(HeritageMetadata))]
    public partial class Heritage {
        }

        public class HeritageMetadata{
            [Display(Name = "Listing Status")] 
            public int ListingStatus;
            [Display(Name = "Existing Structure Age")]
            public int ExistingStructureAge;
            [Display(Name = "Conservation Management Plan?")]
            public int ConservationManagementPlan;
        }

    public class HeritageViewModel {
        public int StructuresId { get; set; }
        public int ListingStatus { get; set; }
        public int ExistingStructureAge { get; set; }
        public bool ConservationManagementPlan { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ListingStatusTypes { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ExistingStructureAgeTypes { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with putting those attributes on the view model. Infact try to keep those independent. Loosly coupled systems is what we want.

Comment: The attributes need to be on the view model, and since `DisplayAttribute` is a view specific attribute, it should not even be on the data model.